# Dev server not hot-reloading, failing to build

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader, hapi.js

I'm working on a react/redux app, served up locally with a npm-piped hapi.js backend on port:3000, and a webpack-dev-server running on port:3001;

I have a couple api routes on teh back to serve up static files, and then I hit asset files out of my build/public directory with a {param*} rule. To make that work, I have a proxy on the WebpackDevServer that forwards requests back to port:3000

I have `CSSModules` performing a build of .`scss`, and there are a couple of other loaders in place.

When I first set this up, it worked as expected. I could add files, save content, perform the build and the HMR would do its thing, and update the dom. Worked great. At some point, this stopped working very well. The backend on :3000 does a rebuild and reload, while the front end on :3001 is receiving an error like so:

```
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
bundle.js:26 GET http://localhost:3001/dist/ee2fe9b049ee40ff922c.hot-update.json 404 (Not Found)hotDownloadManifest @ bundle.js:26hotCheck @ bundle.js:245check @ bundle.js:8080(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:8138
bundle.js:8095 [HMR] Cannot find update. Need to do a full reload!
bundle.js:8096 [HMR] (Probably because of restarting the webpack-dev-server)
```

I notice there is a reference to :8080 in there (the webpack-dev-server default), but my references are all to :3000/1.

When this stack was working well - I could save the server.js and the hapi server would restart itself (due to the npm piping), and the webpack build would go as expected. Currently the build **failing** intermittently from server.js, and I'm must manually `$ webpack` and reload the browser to trigger the build and successful refresh. Which is obviously defeating the point.

**The Important Bits :**

server.js

```
// ... hapi.js settings

// Dev server / HMR
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const config = require('../../webpack.config.js');

if (!isProduction){
  new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: 'dist',
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      "*": 'http://localhost:3000'
    },
    quiet: false,
    stats: { colors: true }
  }).listen(3001, 'localhost', (err, result) => {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('WebpackDevServer[localhost::3001]');
  });
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
// imports
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const validate = require('webpack-validator');
const path = require('path');

// paths
const rootPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'src');

// configger the almighty webpack
const config = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.resolve(rootPath, 'index.jsx')
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    root: rootPath
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.map'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        loader: 'react-hot!babel',
        include: rootPath
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass'),
        include: rootPath
      }, {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=/images/[name].[ext]',
        include: rootPath
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: '#source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: '/public',
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
  ]
};

module.exports = validate(config);
```

Been tinkering with all the settings, so I might of munged what had been working. But it seems this should be functioning as expected.

Any insight into this config stack would be appreciated. 
Project source : [github](https://github.com/Bosworth99/10k_Portfolio)

Best -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp. A bit of tinkering, if anyone else has this issue.

I modified the server.js code to handle all the dev server configurations, which now means that if I view the site at `:3001`, saves do perform a rebuild into memory, and those are served up on the fly. Which is good.

As I understand it, the below WebpackDevServer config will not actually rebuild new files (as the [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) seem to indicate). I still have to `$ webpack` manually to actually build the files. I doubt this is the correct behavior, but if I'm getting a live reload, then that's pretty good. I just have to stay on `:3001`.

server.js

```
// Dev server / HMR
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const config = require('../../webpack.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(config);

new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
  port: 3001,
  publicPath: '/dist/',
  contentBase: 'dist/',
  historyApiFallback: true,
  inline: true,
  hot: false,
  quiet: false,
  stats: { colors: true },
  proxy: {
    '*': 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}).listen(3001, 'localhost', (err, result) => {
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('WebpackDevServer[localhost::3001]');
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
// imports
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const validate = require('webpack-validator');
const path = require('path');

// paths
const rootPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'src');

// configger the almighty webpack
const config = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.resolve(rootPath, 'index.jsx')
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    root: rootPath
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.map'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        loader: 'react-hot!babel',
        include: rootPath
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass'),
        include: rootPath
      }, {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=/images/[name].[ext]',
        include: rootPath
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: '#source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
  ]
};

module.exports = validate(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related with HMR, somehow the webpack dev server receives the 'signal' of a file change, but then is unable to determine which portion of code to update, so it reloads the whole page.

I'm using a slightly different configuration from the one you are using, but there are some odds at first sight:

- in the resolve object, you have '' (empty string) in the array of recognized extensions. Is that voluntary? tell me why you placed that empty string, I've never seen it, I'm curious :)
- The 8080 reference is probably a line number, not a port! At least, seems like that by looking at the following js file names mentions.
- Try to replace the * of the webpack proxy config with another regex... It's just an idea. Webpack dev server must be able theorically to say: hey! This url must be forwarded to the backend. While other urls must not. I don't know how the server interprets the regex, maybe the asterisk is too strong as rule, and makes the configuration to not work properly.
- hot must be set to true if you want HMR.

On my setup instead of using local host, I've configured a vhost on apache and in the hosts file. Not sure if local host can lead to problems, but I've tried to follow as much as possible what I've seen in the documentation.

Don't consider my answer as 100% right, I'm new too with webpack and I'm stuck with some problems too (just uploaded a question a couple of hours ago).
I hope anyway that this can be useful.

Please, can you tell me why you defined the first two entry points? I've already seen that
Thank you